# Помогите понять пример использования php-ml

Tags: php, нейронные-сети

Пару часов пытался разобраться в примере для php-ml. Не понимаю, что имнно в этом примере происходит.
Обучается сеть из csv файла формата `"Текст предложения","язык"`
Вот сам пример

```php
$dataset = new CsvDataset('data/languages.csv', 1);
$vectorizer = new TokenCountVectorizer(new WordTokenizer());
$tfIdfTransformer = new TfIdfTransformer();
$samples = [];
foreach ($dataset->getSamples() as $sample) {
    $samples[] = $sample[0];
}
$vectorizer->fit($samples);
$vectorizer->transform($samples);
$tfIdfTransformer->fit($samples);
$tfIdfTransformer->transform($samples);
$dataset = new ArrayDataset($samples, $dataset->getTargets());
$randomSplit = new StratifiedRandomSplit($dataset, 0.1);
$classifier = new SVC(Kernel::RBF, 10000);
$classifier->train($randomSplit->getTrainSamples(), $randomSplit->getTrainLabels());
$predictedLabels = $classifier->predict($randomSplit->getTestSamples());
echo 'Accuracy: '.Accuracy::score($randomSplit->getTestLabels(), $predictedLabels);
```

Не понятно, где именно происходит ввод данных на вход. Понял лишь то, что на вход подаются данные, на которых сеть и обучалась.

Как мне подать на вход свой текст и определить, насколько вероятно, что это предложение написано на английском языке?

Вот ссылка на сам пример [php-ml-examples/classification/languageDetection.php](https://github.com/php-ai/php-ml-examples/blob/master/classification/languageDetection.php)

И на библиотеку https://github.com/php-ai/php-ml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Код написан в классическом стиле.

Код с комментами (как они обозначаются на *php* я не знаю, так что не серчайте). В комментах могут быть неточности, поскольку я не разбирался в библиотеке, которую Вы используете.

```
# Читаем датку из csv в таблицу объект-признак (судя по коду, в целом, там текстовые данные)
$dataset = new CsvDataset('data/languages.csv', 1);
# Создаём объект парсера
$vectorizer = new TokenCountVectorizer(new WordTokenizer());
# Создаём Tf-Idf преобразователь
$tfIdfTransformer = new TfIdfTransformer();
$samples = [];
# Запихиваем датку объект за объектом в массив (построчно)
foreach ($dataset->getSamples() as $sample) {
    $samples[] = $sample[0];
}
# Разбиваем дату на токены ("инициализация") и получаем непосредственно разбитые данные (вероятно, на слова)
$vectorizer->fit($samples);
$vectorizer->transform($samples);
# Строим Tf-Idf("инициализация") и получаем непосредственно разбитые данные (вероятно, на слова)
$tfIdfTransformer->fit($samples);
$tfIdfTransformer->transform($samples);
# Преобразуем данные к удобному виду (X, y) == (фичи, класс)
$dataset = new ArrayDataset($samples, $dataset->getTargets());
# Делим данные на 2 части: обучающее множество и валидационное
$randomSplit = new StratifiedRandomSplit($dataset, 0.1);
# Создаём объект модели с ядром RBF, второй параметр не понимаю зачем нужен
$classifier = new SVC(Kernel::RBF, 10000);
# Треним модель на trainSet
$classifier->train($randomSplit->getTrainSamples(), $randomSplit->getTrainLabels());
# Делаем оценку и смотрим на результат на тестовом множестве
$predictedLabels = $classifier->predict($randomSplit->getTestSamples());
echo 'Accuracy: '.Accuracy::score($randomSplit->getTestLabels(), $predictedLabels);
```

Также есть ощущение, что в коде заложена логическая бомба, которая заключается в том, что в `tfIdfTransformer` и `vectorizer` передаются данные вместе с метками классов. Кроме того, у меня вызывают некоторые сомнения конструкции, связанные с `vectorizer`, `tfIdfTransformer`.

Кроме того, хорошо бы смотреть не только precision, но и recall. Об этом можно прочитать [здесь](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall). Этот вопрос связан с тем, что выборка может быть несбалансированной, т.е. в классе **0** у Вас 100000 сообщений, а в классе **1** -- 100. В таком случае, оценка получится завышенной. Также, для Вашей задачи, в данной постановке, при наличии 2х классов, можно использовать [F-меру](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA#F-.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B0_.28F-measure.2C_.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B0_.D0.92.D0.B0.D0.BD_.D0.A0.D0.B8.D0.B7.D0.B1.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B3.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B0.29). Более подробно можете поискать информацию в одном из этих блогах о способах оценки алгоритмов: [раз](http://bazhenov.me/blog/2012/07/21/classification-performance-evaluation.html), [два](https://alexanderdyakonov.wordpress.com/). Конечно, в Вашем случае этот аспект невилируется, поскольку разбиение на testSet и на trainSet производится сбалансированно (об этом говорит слово `Stratified`). Но, если данные изначально несбалансированны, то с ними фундаментально ничего не сделаешь. И необходимо считать как *recall*, так и `precision`.

Также замечу, что не производится [CrossValidation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)), в связи с этим, точность оценки модели может сильно варьироваться. Кросс-валидация состоит в том, что разбиение на тестовое и валидационное множество производится многократно. В вашем случае это делается случайным образом. Т.е.:

- B тестовый набор данных берётся 10%, в обучающий набор данных берётся 90%
- Производится обучение модели на тестовом наборе
- Производится оценка модели
- Тестовый набор данных разбивается другим способом на 10% в тестовый набор, в обущающий -- 90%.
- ...

Так проделывается много раз. Все полученные результаты усредняются. За счёт усреднёния погрешности при оценке компенсируются.

Comment: Спасибо за такой хороший подробный ответ. Теперь мне полностью стало понятно, почему каждый раз пример выдавал разные результаты. Попробую вместо деления 10 к 1 построить 2 датасета на реальных данных.

Comment: @ilyaplot для повторения экспериментов часто используется параметр в моделях `random_state`. В таком случае, псевдослучайные числа при каждом запуске меняться не будут.